# How to configure D-Link DSL-2320B modem for att.com

Tags: dsl-modem

How to configure new D-Link DSL-2320B modem replacing Motorola modem that needs two ice pack to operate. Wireless router is D-Link DIR-655. Am able to talk to the modem 192.168.1.1 and the router 192.168.0.1 via wireless. Account with att.com.

The existing ice-pack modem has:

- [PPP on the modem] Mode
- [0] VPI
- [35] VPI
- [Never] Timeoput
- [151.164.184.145] IP Gateway

Current attempt on the new modem:

ATM PVC Configuration.

- (-) DSL Auto-connect
- [0] VPI
- [35] VCI
- [X]  PPP over Ethernet (PPPoE)
- [VCMUX|LLC/SNAP-BRIDGING]  Encapsulation Mode
- [AUTOPAP|CHAP|MSCHAP] Authentication Method
- (?) Dial on demand (with idle timeout timer)
- [???] Inactivity Timeout (minutes)
- (?) PPP IP extension
- (?) Keep Alive
- (?) Use Static IP Address
- (?)  Obtain default gateway automatically
- (?) Use the following default gateway:

  - [???] Use IP Address
  - [???] Use WAN Interface

When unplugging phone line from the existing modem then plugging phone line into the new modem and letting it "auto-connect" it says that 0/35 is busy and tries a bunch of other values.

Powering down the existing modem overnight did not change the result.

Telling the existing modem to "disconnect" did not change the result.

Answer (score 2):

Take the D-Link modem, receipt and a twenty dollar bill to the retailer, come home with a Motorola 2210-02, plug in cables, enter username/password and resume surfing (keep ice packs ready for next spring). This is the fourth modem with the Motorola logo.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like AT&T DSL uses PPPoE, and you can setup the PPPoE connection in either your modem or your router. So, it looks like you can do one of the following:

- Setup your modem for bridged mode, and setup the PPPoE connection in your router.

**OR**

- Setup the PPPoE connection in your modem, and setup your router for Dynamic IP.

Refer to the manuals for your equipment for help with those settings. I've linked to them below if you don't have them or if other people want to assist further.

If you need to setup the VPI and VCI in the modem, [this PDF file](http://www.att.com/support_media/images/pdf/hsi/ATT+HSI+Self-Installation+Guide+-13.pdf) says the VPI is either 0 or 8 (depending on what state you live in), and the VCI is 35.

When you setup the PPPoE, the username is your complete e-mail address (username@att.net), and the password is your e-mail password.

**Links**

[D-Link DSL-2320B ADSL2/2+ Ethernet/USB Modem](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=554)
-- [Product Manual](ftp://ftp.dlink.com/Broadband/dsl2320B/Manual/dsl2320B_Manual_12.zip) -- [Emulator](http://www.support.dlink.com/emulators/dsl2320b/) -- [Front image](http://images.dlink.com/new/products/DSL-2320B/DSL-2320B_front.jpg)

[D-Link DIR-655 Xtreme N Gigabit Router](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=530)
-- [Product Manual](ftp://ftp.dlink.com/Gateway/dir655/Manual/dir655_manual_150.zip) -- [Emulator](http://support.dlink.com/Emulators/dir655/132NA/login.html) -- [Front image](http://images.dlink.com/new/products/DIR-655/DIR-655_front.jpg) -- [Back image](http://images.dlink.com/new/products/DIR-655/DIR-655_back.jpg)

[AT&T High Speed Interent Self-Installation Guide for Modem Equipment](http://www.att.com/support_media/images/pdf/hsi/ATT+HSI+Self-Installation+Guide+-13.pdf)